# Python : failed to get dictionary in a function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my first time working with Django and working after a very long time with Python. I have class method that should accept dictionary using `**kwargs` but it is responding with `"insertToLeadHelper() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"`

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.views import APIView
class test(APIView):
    """
    A view that can accept POST requests with JSON content.
    """
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )
    def insertToLeadHelper(self, **data):
        print data


    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print "here"
        self.insertToLeadHelper(request.data)
        return Response({"status" : request.data},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Please help

Comment: I wonder what is `request.data`?

Comment: Show us your dictionary and how do you invoke your method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using the `**kwargs` syntax? You're passing a dictionary directly, you don't want to decompose it into kwargs. Just accept the data dict:

```
def insertToLeadHelper(self, data):
```

Comment: that worked. But can you please clarify when I exactly should i use **kwargs?